# Is there a way to build an array of toggle buttons and track all buttons that have been clicked?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building a GUI which consists of a large array of toggle buttons (25 by 25) using wxPython. I have used GridSizer and AddMany to create the grid of togglebuttons. I'm not able to assign individual buttons to a variable with the AddMany syntax and hence, i'm not sure how I can track the clicked togglebuttons

This is my first attempt at using wxpython library to build an application and I'm not very familiar with its more powerful features. My past projects have only involved a few buttons and did not need a large grid of buttons

```py
gs = wx.GridSizer(12, 12, 4, 4)

gs.AddMany( [(wx.ToggleButton(self, label='Cls'), 2, wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.ToggleButton(self, label='Bck'), 2, wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.ToggleButton(self, label='Close'), 2, wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.ToggleButton(self, label='7'), 2, wx.EXPAND),
#lots of buttons
            (wx.ToggleButton(self, label='8'), 0, wx.EXPAND),
            (wx.ToggleButton(self, label='9'), 0, wx.EXPAND)])
```

I'm not able to find good advice or example on the internet and I'm hoping some experts of wxpython can help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `label` or give each button a `name`, whilst storing their current values in a `dictionary`.
For example:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button_dict = {'Info':False,'Error':False,'Question':False}
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 2, 2)
        sizer.AddMany([wx.ToggleButton(panel, label='Info'), wx.ToggleButton(panel, label='Error'), wx.ToggleButton(panel, label='Question')])
        hbox.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 15)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.ShowButton)
        self.SetSize((300, 200))
        self.SetTitle('Buttons')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def ShowButton(self, event):
        x = event.GetEventObject()
        lab = x.GetLabel()
        print("Button pressed",lab)
        if self.button_dict[lab]:
            self.button_dict[lab] = False
        else:
            self.button_dict[lab] = True
        print(self.button_dict)

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Changing foreground colour image based on comment:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.What is an effective way to change the background color of the selected buttons in this case?

Comment: The background colour seems to be controlled by the system/style and so may or may not work, depending on the machine your code is running on. However, the foreground colour appears to be more forgiving. Try: `x.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLUE)` etc in your if statement.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that Windows10 does not support either of them: SetForegroundColour or SetBackgroundColour.

Comment: I no nothing of windows after Win95, if you have the option of changing desktop themes, have a dig around in those.